# Problems when trying to connect XBox One S Controller to PC

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

I try to connect my XBox One S Controller to PC via Bluetooth. I can see a controller named "Gamecontroller", sometimes it has the name "Xbox Wireless Controller". When I try to pair now I have to enter a pair code or something. When I leave it blank and just press OK it seems to install the driver or something and then is "connected". But my controller's XBox button is still blinking and I cannot use it. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdv5OUvc75Y

Comment: @DrZoo that's the part that doesn't work^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Bluetooth 4 is needed. Bought a new Bluetooth adapter and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: It didn't work for me. My Pc has bluetooth 4.2

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution. My wife had the same problem after the firmware update, so I fixed it that way:

- Plug the controller by USB on the PC
- Uninstall the driver of the contriller in the "device manager"
- Unplug the controller and turn it off
- Turn it on again and pared it by bluetooth again

After these steps, it should work.

Comment: After trying everything I could find on the internet, this is what ended up working for me. Awesome. +1

Answer (score 1):

I have three recommendations to solve your problems.

**#1**

Since it is one of the features of the new Xbox One S controller to be able to connect wirelessly to your pc, I suggest you

- restart your controller by pressing and holding the home button for 6 seconds
- remove the controller from your pc devices. Go to Settings > Devices > Bluetooth. Then you can select the controller and then select "Remove device."
- then follow the steps in this video [Use Bluetooth to connect your Xbox One controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deXVHQ1wJXc)

**#2**

The alternative & best way to connect a Xbox One controller to your PC is to buy this: [image: xbox one controller windows]

It doesn't cost much, you can get for less than $20 on Amazon, and trust me my friend when I tell you it will make your life easier. You simply plug it in the USB port of your pc and connect your controller wirelessly. Magic! Also it supports up to 8 controllers simultaneously as well as 4 chat headsets and 2 stereo headsets, so it's definitely worth it in my opinion!

**#3**

If you need to use the controller urgently and the first solution did't work, just use a micro usb cable to play temporarily until you get the problem fixed.
It looks like this: [image: micro usb cable]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did try to install it on 2 different computers, removed it 10 times, restarted the controller and the computer and nothing. And I don't see why I should buy that, if Bluetooth is one of the features and the reason why I bought it. And yes I can play with it via cable. Just want to have it working wireless.

Comment: Yeah that's strange if you restarted everything, maybe something's wrong with your controller? Have you tried contacting Xbox support explaining the problem. Also I just recommended buying the adapter to play with Xbox One controllers as well if you're going to play with siblings or friends, could have been useful to you. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help :/

Comment: The controller works with the xbox one tho... Yea so the next step has to be contacting xbox support. and no I need the controller only for me. thanks for your effort tho!

Comment: Good luck man, do let me know I'm actually curious to find out what the problem is. Since it works with the Xbox then the bluetooth is fine, so I'm guessing the issue has to do with the linking process on pc, but I'm out of ideas man haha

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 10? You may need to update the controllers firmware to establish a proper connection. You can do this either by connecting the controller to your Xbox One while connected to the internet, or connect it to your PC with a micro USB cord. See [this](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.xbox.com/xboxone/controllerupdate&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjf9e-HnMfUAhVR0WMKHfiVA78QFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNHbOOyuPwqkUW0XZHxabQEMUQ2wzg) link for updating the firmware through a PC.

To pair the controller, hold the sync button on the top-left of the controller while you search for new bluetooth devices on your PC. It *should* appear as "Xbox One wireless controller for Windows" as you stated.

If you still have issues connecting your controller, you can also use the [Moga Serial to Windows Interface](https://github.com/Zel-os/MogaSerial) tool to use the controller as an XInput HID. Be certain to use the Xinput option with the utility.

Xbox One S wireless controllers use Bluetooth 3.0 communication protocol. I have  used this method sucessfully on Windows 7, 8, and 10.